# Space Physics for missiles, spaceships - Learning Calculus edition

Tags: math, physics, calculus

Supposing we have Missile A, with a position vector and velocity magnitude (ignoring acceleration, as many games do) and Spaceship B, with position and velocity vectors. Now, this missile, being a Nasty Missile of Seeking, will try to find the best intercept for Spaceship B.

Missile A has two advantages: It knows calculus and it can calculate the roots of polynomials. However, the missile, or to abstract, the programmer, is still learning calculus and wants to know if he has the right equation. (Polynomial roots will be solved by a nice fellow called Jenkins-Traub Code Implemented From Netlib)

To wit:

- mp = Missile Position
- mv = Missile Velocity
- sp = Spaceship Position
- sv = Spaceship Velocity
- t = Time

According to the programmer's best guess, the equation for intercept is:
t*sp*sv + t*sp*mv - t*mp*sv - t*mp*mv

Except I'm pretty sure I'm headed down the wrong track entirely, as there should probably be some exponents in that mess; this being an attempt at solving:
(sp-mp)(sv-mv)(t)

My other option is differentiating (sp-mp)(sv-mv)^2, but I wanted to get feedback first, partly because, unless I'm mistaken, '(sp-mp)' resolves to '1'. And that seems...Odd. OTOH, the rate at which that function is changing might be what I'm looking for.

So - What have I gotten wrong, where and why?

Thanks.

[Potentially-useful link to first thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278636/re-space-physics-for-missiles-spaceships)

Edit:

Summing the equations:

(a+bx) + (c+ex)

(a+1bx^0) + (c+1ex^0)

(a+1) + (c+1)

Non-viable.

Product of the equations:

(a+bx)(c+ex)

ac+aex+cbx+bex^2

Not a polynomial (can't solve with Jenkins-Traub) and doesn't quite look right.

ac+1aex^0+1cbx^0+2bex^1

ac+ae+cb+2bex

And definitely not that, I think.

Comment: You forgot to mention what the space ship and the missile can control. Can they speed up or down? Can they change direction,...

Comment: My comment is to always start with a good sketch. Once you lay all your objects and variables on the sketch the solution will become more obvious. You reminded me I solved this problem (with gravity) for a game when I was learning how to program using BASIC. You best learn when you figure it out yourself.

Comment: What's the unknown? What quantity are you trying to calculate? What does "equation for intercept" mean?

Comment: Ah, sorry. In order: That's disregarded, the best intercept at that moment is all that's needed. Well, yes, I'm trying to figure it out myself; thanks for the suggestion to sketch it out. I'm trying to derive a polynomial equation which will give the time at which, given this instant's values, the missile can intercept the spaceship. Why a polynomial equation? Well, gotta be some type of equation. And I know a polynomial will work.

Comment: Without accelerations the equations are linear. No polynomial is needed. With gravity you will get a 2nd order poly.

Comment: Ah - I was unclear there - I'm counting a linear equation (when one pops up) as a polynomial with a highest exponent of 1.

Answer (score 2):

The 2D equations of motion for the missile are (assume starting at t=0)

```
[ mpx(t) = mpx(0) + mvx*t , mpy(t) = mpy(0) + mvy*t ]
```

the spaceship motion is

```
[ spx(t) = spx(0) + svx*t , spy(t) = spy(0) + svy*t ]
```

where `mpx(0)` `mpy(0)` `spx(0)` `spy(0)` are the initial position components

So to intersect you must have `mpx(t)=spx(t)` and `mpy(t)=spy(t)`. Which is two equations to solve for two unknowns. One may be the time to intercept `t`, and the other the direction of the missile given by `slope=mvy/mvx`. Or it could be the initial position of the missle `mpx(0)` and `mpy(0)`, or the velocity components given a target intercept time.

It is not clear from the question what you a looking for.

Comment: It has to be *two* things, since there are two equations.

Comment: Ah, well that makes sense. The other thing would be the direction for the missile to move.

Answer (score 0):

#### Instantaneous Solution

`Position_Ship + t*Velocity_Ship = Position_Missile + t*Velocity_Missile`

If they are set to intercept then you can trivially solve for `t` over either dimension.

If you want to determine `Velocity_Missile` we need one more constraint.

`N = (Position_Missile - Position_Ship) ^ Velocity_Ship` (cross-product)

`N dot Velocity_Missle = 0`

This will give you a pair or linear simultaneous equations.

#### Dynamic Solution

If the `Velocity_Missile` is initially given and we want to apply accelleration until we get within a limiting radius, then it becomes thorny. You can get an aesthetically pleasing solution using a simple curve of persuit, or we can get numerical...

Let `Velocity_Missile'` be the instantaneous solutions from above, derive the corresponding `t'`, given the power of the motor you can calculate the time `t''` taken to deliver that change in velocity. Add this `t''*Ship_Velocity` to get an updated target position. Iterate.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for help to solve it myself, not for a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have mp, mv and sp, then to calculate sv and t:

```
mp+mv(t)=sp+sv(t) and |sv|=q (maxspeed)
mp+mv(t)-sp+sv(t)=0

mpx+mvx*t-spx+svx*t=0
mpy+mvy*t-spy+svy*t=0

svx^2+svy^2=q^2
svx^2+svy^2-q^2=0
```

Which we then can solve:

```
(mpx-spx)/t+mvx=svx
(mpy-spy)/t+mvy=svy

((mpx-spx)/t+mvx)^2+((mpy-spy)/t+mvy)^2=q^2
(mpx-spx)^2/t^2+2*mvx*(mpx-spx)/t+mvx^2+(mpy-spy)^2/t^2+2*mvy*(mpy-spy)/t+mvy^2=q^2
((mpx-spx)^2+(mpy-spy)^2)/t^2+(2*mvx*(mpx-spx)+2*mvy*(mpy-spy))/t+mvx^2+mvy^2-q^2=0
((mpx-spx)^2+(mpy-spy)^2)+(2*mvx*(mpx-spx)+2*mvy*(mpy-spy))*t+(mvx^2+mvy^2-q^2)*t^2=0
((mpx-spx)^2+(mpy-spy)^2)/(mvx^2+mvy^2-q^2)+(2*mvx*(mpx-spx)+2*mvy*(mpy-spy))/(mvx^2+mvy^2-q^2)*t+t^2=0

c = (mvx^2+mvy^2-q^2)
if   a = (2*mvx*(mpx-spx)+2*mvy*(mpy-spy))/c
and  b = ((mpx-spx)^2+(mpy-spy)^2)/c
then t = -a/2+-sqrt(a^2/4-b)

a/2 = (2*mvx*(mpx-spx)+2*mvy*(mpy-spy))/2c
a/2 = (mvx*(mpx-spx)+mvy*(mpy-spy))/c
a^2/4 = (mvx^2*(mpx-spx)^2+2*mvx*(mpx-spx)*mvy*(mpy-spy)+mvy^2*(mpy-spy)^2)/c^2

b/c^2=((mpx-spx)^2+(mpy-spy)^2)*c
b/c^2=((mpx-spx)^2+(mpy-spy)^2)*(mvx^2+mvy^2-q^2)
b/c^2=mvx^2(mpx-spx)^2+mvx^2(mpy-spy)^2+mvy^2(mpx-spx)^2+mvy^2(mpy-spy)^2-q^2(mpx-spx)^2-q^2(mpy-spy)^2

t = -(mvx*(mpx-spx)+mvy*(mpy-spy))/c +- sqrt((mvx^2*(mpx-spx)^2+2*mvx*(mpx-spx)*mvy*(mpy-spy)+mvy^2*(mpy-spy)^2)-(mvx^2(mpx-spx)^2+mvx^2(mpy-spy)^2+mvy^2(mpx-spx)^2+mvy^2(mpy-spy)^2-q^2(mpx-spx)^2-q^2(mpy-spy)^2))/c

t = -(mvx*(mpx-spx)+mvy*(mpy-spy))/c +- sqrt((2*mvx*(mpx-spx)*mvy*(mpy-spy))-(mvx^2(mpy-spy)^2+mvy^2(mpx-spx)^2)+q^2((mpx-spx)^2+(mpy-spy)^2)))/c

t = -(mvx*(mpx-spx)+mvy*(mpy-spy))/c +- sqrt(-(mvx(mpy-spy)-mvy(mpx-spx))^2+q^2((mpx-spx)^2+(mpy-spy)^2)))/c

t = -(mvx*(mpx-spx)+mvy*(mpy-spy))/c +- sqrt(-(mvx(mpy-spy)-mvy(mpx-spx))^2+q^2(c+q^2))/c
t = -(mvx*(mpx-spx)+mvy*(mpy-spy))/c +- sqrt(-(mvx(mpy-spy)-mvy(mpx-spx))^2+q^2(c+q^2))/c

t = -(mvx*(mpx-spx)+mvy*(mpy-spy))/c +- sqrt(-(mvx(mpy-spy)-mvy(mpx-spx))^2+q^2(c+q^2))/(mvx^2+mvy^2-q^2)
```

I don't have time to simplify further, but it can be done, or just evaluate it.

Then plug t back into:

```
svx=(mpx-spx)/t+mvx
svy=(mpy-spy)/t+mvy
```

To get the s vector.

Maybe I've done a mistake somewhere...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for help to solve it myself, not for a solution. :)